# Joining values in an Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

Say I have:

```
var Certificated = {}
```

Sub items are added dynamically and variate. Possible outcome:

```
var Certificated = {
    Elementary: ["foo","bar", "ball"]
    MiddleSchool: ["bar", "crampapydime"]
};
```

I want to do the following:

```
Certificated.Elementary = Certificated.Elementary.join("");
```

Except I need it to do that on all of the objects inside.

Keep in mind I can't know for sure the titles of nor how many objects will be inside `Certificated`.

My question is how can I use `.join("")` on all elements inside `Certificated`, without calling each one specifically?

**EDIT:** I am aware .join() is for arrays and the objects inside Certificated are going to be arrays. Therefore the join method.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(Certificated)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
for (var key in Certificated) {
    if (Certificated.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        Certificated[key] = Certificated[key].join("");
    }
}
```

It loops through all properties of `Certificated`, and makes a quick safe check for the `key` being a real property, then uses bracket notation - `[""]` - to do your `join`.

Quick question - are you sure you want to use `join`? I know you just provided an example, but you can't call `join` on a string...it's for arrays. Just wanted to make sure you knew.

Here's a jsFiddle of my code working with arrays being used for the properties:

http://jsfiddle.net/v48dL/

Notice in the browser console, the properties' values are strings because the `join` combined them with `""`.

Comment: +1 for the key test! And yes, I updated my question to clarify that I planned to use the .join() on an array. I figured it was implied.

Comment: @JonnySooter Awesome, glad it helped. I thought you were implying, but I didn't want to assume too much. Nonetheless, I would've been glad to work with you if I hadn't understood :)